# Maintaining state within a stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a heavy load flow of users data. I want to determine if this is a new user by it's id. In order to reduce calls to the db I rather maintain a state in memory of previous users.

```
val users = mutable.set[String]()
//init the state from db
user = db.getAllUsersIds()
val source: Source[User, NotUsed]
val dbSink: Sink[User, NotUsed] //goes to db
//if the user is added to the set it will return true
val usersFilter = Flow[User].filter(user => users.add(user.id))
```

now I can create a graph

```
source ~> usersFilter ~> dbSink
```

my problem is that the mutable state is shared and unsafe. Is there an option to maintain the state within the flow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this.

If you are getting a streams of records and you want to deduplicate the stream (because some ids are already processed). You can do

http://janschulte.com/2016/03/08/deduplicate-akka-stream/

The other way of doing this is via database lookups where you check if the ID already exists.

```
val alreadyExists : Flow[User, NotUsed] = {
  // build a cache of known ids
  val knownIdList = ... // query database and get list of IDs
  Flow[User].filterNot(user => knownIdList.contains(user.id))
}
```

Comment: there is main flaw in your suggestion. 
It will require a lot of requests to the db which means a lot of io. I rather maintain it in memory (I will update my post)

Comment: At least in my case I make only 1 call to the DB and load all the existing ids in a single query into a list. then just lookup on the list ( or map) in the flow at runtime.

Comment: do you think something like this will work ?
e.g 
`def alreadyExists = {
    val alreadyExistingIds = mutable.set[String](init from db)
    Flow[User].filterNot(user => alreadyExistingIds.add(user.id))
}`

Comment: yes this should work because your mutable list is still only in the scope of the already exists flow. so no one else can see it.

Comment: After doing the add. you still need to return true/false for the filterNot to work.

Comment: of course. but wouldn't `alreadyExists` will be re-evaluated on every call i.e on every incoming user ? wouldn't it better to define it as `val` ?

Comment: No its called only when the RunnableGraph is built. Also I updated the answer to include one more way of achieving what you want.